# Define date time at run time of PHP script

Tags: php, date

I'm currently developing an application which manages delivery rules for an e-commerce website. I need to test certain days of the week and times of the day to test they have different delivery rules. Unfortunately, I'm working on a server with multiple other projects so can't edit the OS time/time date.

Similar to how [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) can define the timezone and *sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script* . Is there something I can run at the start of my script to define the time and date in full and is globally applied? I really would like to test Christmas time for example.

Comment: That's why you need to have a production and testing environments

Comment: Use docker. It'll allow you to specify different system settings and is very easy to use.

Comment: Alon, true but my testing/development environment is used by other developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any such functions for PHP. As far as I know is this information directly fetched from the operating system.

What you could do, to ease testing, is to have a single method for fetching the current day/timestamp. This would allow simpler unit testing.

For example, if you need to fetch the current date, somewhere in your function.

Utility class:

```
class DateUtility {
    public static function getCurrentDate() {
        if (!Config::get('debug')) {
            return date('j-M-Y');
        }

        return date('j-M-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, Config::get('debug-month'), Config::get('debug-day'), Config::get('debug-year'));
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$date = DateUtility::getCurrentDate();
set_delivery_date($date);
```

Note that this example is extremely simplified. You most likely need to have a more general implementation in your system, especially if you deal a lot with date, timezones and stuff like that. Also note that if you use functions such as `NOW()` in MySQL (or similar), will this need to be handled specially too.